# why does variable not update value

Tags: php, html, ajax

Why does my variable `$color` not update in the `<h3>` because if I `echo "$color"` it shows the updated color but the `<h3>` is in the same color no matter what.

*index.php*

```
 <?php
 $color = "#29abe2";
 if ($reservationAvailable['data']['is_reservation_possible'] == true){
    $color = "#29abe2";
 }else{
    $color = "#cc00cc";
 }
 ?>
 <h3 style="color: <?php echo "$color"; ?>" id="testajax">Vul de datum, begin tijd, tijdsduur en aantal sloepen in.</h3>
```

*script.js*

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    var date = "";
    var begin = "";
    var tijdsduur = "";
    var aantal = "";


    $('#datum').change(function() {
        date = $("#datum").val();
        console.log(date);
    });
    $('#beginTijd').change(function() {
        begin = ($(this).val());
        console.log(begin);
    });
    $('#Tijdsduur').change(function() {
        tijdsduur = ($(this).val());
        console.log(tijdsduur);
    });
    $('#aantalSloepen').change(function() {
        aantal = ($(this).val());
        console.log(aantal);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "index.php",
            data: {
                date: date,
                begin: begin,
                eind: tijdsduur,
                quantity: aantal
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $('#testajax').html(data);
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Op wrote this in comment : `Yes I am updateing it after an ajax call @WilliamPerron – berto`

If you want to change the color after an Ajax call, you should change the color inside your `success` part :

```
// your ajax call
success : function(response) {
    var color = "#29abe2";

    // here you do your test according to what you get 

   $("h3").css("color", color);
},
...
```

EDIT (according to OP comment) :

According to your fiddle, this is what you do :

```
if ($reservationAvailable['data']['is_reservation_possible'] == true){  
    $color = "#29abe2";
    echo "Uw huurprijs exclusief borg: €" . $rentalPrice['data']['total'];
}else{
    $color = "#cc00cc";
    echo $reservationAvailable['data']['reason'];
}
```

You can try this :

PHP:

```
// Add a result array
$result = array();

// YOUR CODE

if ($reservationAvailable['data']['is_reservation_possible'] == true){  
    $result["color"] = "#29abe2";
    $result["message"] = "Uw huurprijs exclusief borg: €" . $rentalPrice['data']['total'];
}else{
    $result["color"] = "#cc00cc";
    $result["message"] = $reservationAvailable['data']['reason'];
}

// Now return this as JSON
echo json_encode($result);
```

JS :

Add this to your Ajax call : `dataType : "json",`

And now you can do this :

```
// your ajax call
success: function(data) {
    $('#testajax').html(response.message);
    $("h3").css("color", response.color);
    console.log(data);
}
...
```

Comment: well I dont know if that is possible because the ajax gives me data then I send that to planyo with gives me data back. and with that data i make this if statement

Comment: I would add that if the purpose of the Ajax request is simply to change the value of an attribute, it should probably target another file/function than `index.php` again, so as to avoid getting html send back from the server.

Comment: @berto I might be wrong, but if you want to change the color without reloading the page, Ajax is the only solution I know. Or you can put this color in session and reload your page using this session value...but that doesn't sound great to just change one color

Comment: I don't really know how to explain it but I made a https://jsfiddle.net/ucsune8u/

Comment: I update an select then ajax sends the data to php where I use a http request to planyo that gives me output and with that output I check if something is true if so I want to display how much it costs in #29abe2 if not I want to show the reason it is not true in #cc00cc.

Comment: The logic could be : 1/ You update an select 2/ You send the data using Ajax 3/ You return a value true or false accordind to your test in php 4/ You change the color according to this value

Comment: yes that is what I mean

Comment: I edited my question to try to solve your problem, tell me if it works for you

Comment: sorry I didn't read you awnser was in some sort of meeting but I fixed it. 
`success: function(data) {
              var color = data.substr(data.length - 7);
              var message = data.slice(0, -7); // "12345.0"
              document.getElementById("testajax").style.color = color;

                $('#testajax').html(message);
                console.log(message);`

and send the color code with php

Comment: thnx for your help anyway@MickaelLeger

Comment: @berto np, glad if I helped :)

Answer (score -1):

What I feel is going on here is that there may be another CSS rule overwriting the rule you wish to use.

You can use `!important` in the following ways:

- `$color = "#29abe2 !important";`
- `style="color: <?php echo "$color !important";`

That, and/or that your conditional statement failed.

Check for errors using error reporting, should this be the case.

- https://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: I don't think so, inline styles > extern styles (if the extern styles are not Important)

Comment: I'm hesitant to upvote since OP stated in comments that adding in `!important` didn't work

Comment: I think the problem is more about how he changes the color since using `style` in an HTML element is priority 1 > `style` in `<head>...</head>` > `.css` file

Comment: @JaxCze why not? I don't post untested code.

Comment: @WilliamPerron the question is unclear then.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner definitely is

Comment: I am updating it after an ajax call @JaxCze

Comment: Note: I don't mind the downvotes. If I am completely wrong about this, I will gladly delete.

Comment: I won't be deleting my answer after all, since it was based on their original post https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/49630470/1 where I was technically correct.

Comment: I'm just wondering why people were so fast to attack my answer, but decided to be friendlier with the other one. *heh* Oh well, *c'est la vie*. :-)